# send youtube url one page to another page using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to send url from one page to another page using jquery ajax.but in this url we are using special characters as shown below

```
 var video='https://youtube.com/v/e6howcqnxfw&start=25&end=80';

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'video.php',       
                data: 'video='+video,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#popup_box').show(); 
                    $('#video').html(response);     
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
```

but in the next page i am getting the value as `"https://youtube.com/v/e6howcqnxfw"`
   i am getting `var video` value from database.
   in this i am not getting full url then How to get full url with special charecters (&).

Thanks!

Comment: https://youtube.com/v/e6howcqnxfw?start=25&end=80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try?

```
encodeURIComponent()

decodeURIComponent()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `?` Use `?` instead of `&`

```
var video='https://youtube.com/v/e6howcqnxfw?start=25&end=80';
```

Comment: i am getting url value form database,not statically

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to break your URL into several parts:

```
var video='https://youtube.com/v/e6howcqnxfw;
var start_time = 25;
var end_time = 80;
```

Then, your AJAX post will look something like that:

```
$.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'video.php?video='+video+'&start='+start_time+'&end='+end_time,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('#popup_box').show(); 
                    $('#video').html(response);     
                },
                error:function()
                {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
```

Other solution is to escape your whole URL, with the function `encodeURIComponent(video);` and then you can decode the URL (on server side) with `urldecode()` PHP function and get all of the variables.